# Torsion on shafts

Tags: torque

Let us say that torque is applied on the free end of cantilever beam will the angle of twist will be same throughout the shaft??Also in series connection of shafts the total angle of twist is given as sum of angle of twists of individual shafts.so the total angle of twist which we get is at which end??
[image]

Comment: I think you need to flesh out your question a bit more. Could you possibly draw out what you're asking and include an image of it? Showing exactly what you mean "cantilever beam" would go a long way. Also, to what end are you asking the question? Would the shaft be solid or hollow? What is the diameter of the shaft? What is the relationship between the size of the ends and the shaft? Are there any irregularities in the shaft? We need some context to better help you and answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, assuming that the beam is homogenous, then the angle of twist is the same per unit length.

For the second, the angle of twist will be measured at the free end as the other end you show as fixed...

But this looks like homework...

Comment: No it's not homework I have done it lioe that for your better understanding.so do you mean that at fixed end there will be no angle of twist and also at free end we can say that angle of twist as theta 1 but you are saying that it's theta1+theta2.can u explain that

Comment: @user40021 - Better yet, could you please explain the questions I asked in the comment under your question? With what little information you've provided in your question, Mike has done an outstanding job of trying to answer it, but now you're throwing even more questions at us without really explaining anything about the original question. This question should really be closed with the sub-text of not being clear. Please help me not to have to do that.

Comment: In question 2 it is given that theta=theta1+theta2 ,here theta is said that it is total angle of twist at free end but why can't it be theta2 alone at the free end.Hope you understood the question

Comment: Because that means you are assuming that section 1 does not twist, but I did not make that assumption : for me the total angle of twist will be theta1 plus theta2 and the relative amounts will be down to the differences between the two sections, such as diameter difference, different materials possibly etc

Comment: I did understand the question, but if you could provide the modulus of elasticity for the two sections...